# subscript of pointer to incomplete type 'const std::complex<float> when using c++11

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, accelerate-framework

I need to compile a static library in c++11 and LLVM.
This lib use the Accelerated framework, which include veclib framework.

Since i use c++11 i have some errors like :

```
subscript of pointer to incomplete type 'const std::complex<float>'
forward declaration of 'std::complex<float>'
```

the forward declaration is done in the "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vForce.h" file.

Everything compile fine with the standard library.

Does someone experienced this issue ?

Comment: You're using an old SDK (10.7) that predates C++11, so it's really not surprising. Perhaps you could try 10.8 ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it is the same with 10.8 sdk.

Comment: Hi. As all  my funcs are in a single cpp file this should be possible. How can i do this with xcode 4.6 ?

Comment: For each source file you can specify the language/compiler as needed. Pick a sensible default and then just customise the source files that you need to. Or, even simpler, write the performance-critical stuff as C and put it in .c source files and a C interface, and then do whatever you like with the C++ stuff.

Comment: Hi. thanks for your help, but i found a simple solution. I just add "#include <cstdlib>" in the cpp file. It does the job. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I just included the cstdlib file at the top of problematic file.

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

Comment: This isn't an answer. Please add this as additional details to your post and remove this one.